# Spotlight does not index folders or subfolders

Tags: macos, spotlight

After upgrading to OS X 10.9, spotlight only show result for files but not folders. I have checked the preferences and also reindex the parenting folder by adding and removing it to the privacy tab.

If I search for a file name, spotlight shows the file, but if I search for the folder that contains the file, spotlight display nothing. This has never been a problem with 10.7 or 10.8, but only since 10.9 upgrades.